# Using MySQL on Heroku CI

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-ci

I have a Rails app that uses a MySQL database. I'd like to use Heroku CI because of its close integration with pipelines, but I see the following error when setting up the test database:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

It's assuming that I'm using Postgres. I'm using the JawsDB addon for using MySQL on Heroku, so I tried to specify that for my test environment in my app.json file:

```
"environments": {
    "test": {
      "addons": [
        "jawsdb:kitefin"
      ]
    }
  },
```

But that didn't seem to make a difference and I see the same error. Does Heroku force you to use Postgres in CI? If so, I'll have to use another service like CircleCI.

Comment: Adam, did you ever get this to work? We are running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this appending in-dyno:

```
"addons": ["jawsdb:kitefin:in-dyno"]
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci-in-dyno-databases

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. It seems that in-dyno databases are only supported for heroku-redis and heroku-postgresql addons: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci-in-dyno-databases#restrictions